# Is it common in Munchkin to allow characters to reach higher than level 9

Tags: munchkin

I only recently learned that you're not allowed to go above level 9, unless it's from combat (or some special cards).

I had played for years allowing higher levels, except you didn't win until you killed a monster.

Is this a common house rule? Or something similar?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It probably is a common mistake, although it seems pretty clear to me from the [rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf), page 1 under **Starting and Finishing the Game**

> The first player to reach 10th level wins ... but you must reach 10th level by killing a monster, unless a card *specifically* allows you to win another way.

Some amount of people must make the same mistake since it is the first rule included in their [FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/).

> **Important Note #1: Reaching Level 10**
>
> The general rule is that you may not reach Level 10 except by killing a monster. If you are at Level 9 and something else happens that would normally let you go up a level . . . you don't. You stay at Level 9. If you have a card or an ability that lets you mess with another player and get a level in return, you cannot play that card or use that ability.

This is all under the assumption that you aren't playing [Epic Munchkin](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/epic/), where the rule wouldn't apply. (But, a similar 19th & 20th level rule would apply instead)

Answer (score 4):

Basically, if you want to play further, that's completely up to you. You can play to any level, just make sure to respect the "Winning Level" rule.

So if you're playing to level 25 or 30, you can keep going, however, you cannot go from 24 to 25 or 29 to 30 by purchasing a level, or using a *go up a level*-type card.

This does not apply to cards that specifically allow you to gain the winning level.

For example: The *Divine Intervention* card makes all clerics to go up a level, even to the winning level.

Comment: Not true in point 2. Consult this thread: http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?p=1192286

Answer (score 1):

It is not a common house rule and it does affect the balance of the game (such as there is a thing of balance in the game. By limiting you to 9 the game gives you a base level chance of defeating a monster. If you start allowing higher levels it makes you unfairly strong enough to defeat the terminal monster.

If Alice is at level 19 and Bob is at level 9 and they both need to defeat one monster to win. Alice is at an unfair advantage. If however both need to get to level 19 before the terminal kill  then it's more fair. Munchkin is a fairly unbalanced game already but this particular home rule doesn't help. In the first scenario it's much easier for Bob to lose his next monster and fall back to level 8 whereas Alice loses her next monster and falls to 18 and still has only to fight a single other monster for victory whereas Bob needs to defeat two monsters.

You can set the victory level to whatever number you see fit as a house rule but allowing people to use, for instance, level up cards, or sell items beyond that victory point will unbalance a game that's precious already.